# Which keyboard should be displayed for numbers in landscape mode on the iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, landscape

I'm trying to display a numeric keypad, but I'm getting the following warning:

```
Can't find keyplane that supports type 8 for keyboard Wildcat-Landscape-QWERTY-Pad; using 3673479387_Wildcat-Alphabetic-Keyboard_Capital-Letters
```

Answer (score 2):

When this happened to me, I solved it by changing`UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad` to `UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same error. I have yet to confirm this, but it might be that UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad, UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad, and UIKeyboardTypePhonePad just don't work on iPad. See here for more discussion:[Which UIKeyboardType can I use on the iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654101/which-uikeyboardtype-can-i-use-on-the-ipad)

Comment: Another related discussion that supports my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486312/weird-error-while-using-uitextfielddelegate

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem while testing on simulators. I tried the following steps which solved my problem, which you can do as well:

iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> Toggle Software Keyboard