# Weird error while using UITextFieldDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have this error while messing with UITextField delegate:

`Can't find keyplane that supports type 8 for keyboard Wildcat-Landscape-QWERTY-Pad; using 3673479387_Wildcat-Alphabetic-Keyboard_Capital-Letters`

Someone have any idea what is it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And you get that message from what delegate method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for iPad you can't use keyboard type: `Decimal Pad`; you must change it to `Number and Punctuation`, etc