# How to include return button in UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad?

Tags: xcode, io, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate, uikeyboardtype

I am implemented a `UITextField` which is supposed to only let user include decimal numbers. I have changed the keyboard type to `UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad` but there is no return button on this keyboard layout to get out of the text field. I don't want to add extra controls on the keyboard as it looks messy. How can I change the `dot` button to return and change its functionality or is there another alternative?

Comment: Changing the default implementation of a built in keyboard is about as messy as it gets. I'd suggest following convention and allowing a tap outside the keyboard to dismiss it, or adding a next/previous button setup above the keyboard.

Comment: That being said, if you need a return key. You'll need to implement the `UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation` keyboard.

Comment: This link may be usefull for solving your issue.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350484/uitextfield-uikeyboardtypedecimalpad-on-ipad

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default return key doesn't comes with Decimal keyboard type. Use the following code snippet  to acheive that:

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 35.0f)];
    toolbar.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

    // Create a flexible space to align buttons to the right
    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

    // Create a cancel button to dismiss the keyboard
    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(resetView)];

    // Add buttons to the toolbar
    [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace, barButtonItem, nil]];

    // Set the toolbar as accessory view of an UITextField object
    _yourTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding !!